# Master Field Large N limit

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, ads-cft

I would like to ask a question about the so-called ''Master Field''. As far as I understand, this represents a classical configuration in the large n limit (saddle point solution) but there is no systematic way to derive master fields for gauge theories. Is anybody trying to solve this problem anymore? Has the Ads/CFT correspondence partially solved it or hinted towards the right direction by considering the gravity dual of the gauge theory as the ''Master Field''? If you know any relevant review papers please post!

Comment: I found a paper that derives master fields for gauge theory (section 2.5) and for HP gauge theory (section 3.4), respectively. [Link to pdf](cds.cern.ch/record/294104/files/9601022.pdf)

Comment: tnx I will take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I think there has been no success in finding the master field in four dimensions. In two dimensions, they exist (see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9411021) and another recent 2017 reference which cites the former (https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07808).

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files,